# what's the easiest way to configure swagger for web api 2.2?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, swagger

What's the easiest way to configure Swagger for Web API 2.2? I went to swagger.io but there was a lot of random info to process. I'm somewhat familiar with Swagger. It was in place for Web API projects at the last 2 organizations I worked for. But I've never actually tried to set Swagger up from scratch for a new Web API project.

Comment: There's probably a NuGet package to help you here. Here's the first search hit https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle

Comment: Its complex until you implement it. Use Swashbuckle, and follow their docs.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the Nugget package "Swashbuckle" to your Web API project. Then run the solution and hit the solution base url with '/swagger', you will get the default swagger page with your api controller methods in it.